# String reverse, wrong results

Tags: java, string, reverse

So my problem is about getting reversed String but only words which are longer or equals 5 characters.
So if we pass ("Hey fellow warriors") to the method we should get "Hey wollef sroirraw" in return. And my code gives me some weird results which are = "sroirraw fellow warriors ".

Here is my code, please give me some clue. The whitespace after last word shouldn't be returned but I don't know why it is.

```
public class PrimeChecker {

public String spinWords(String sentence) {

    String[] tablica = sentence.split(" ");

    for ( String x : tablica ) {
        int y = 0;
        if (  x.length() >= 5 ) {
            StringBuilder p = new StringBuilder(x).reverse();
            x = p.toString();
        }
        tablica[y] = x;
        y++;            
    }

    StringBuilder wynik = new StringBuilder();

    for ( String z : tablica ) {
        int y = 0;
        tablica[y] = z;
        wynik.append(tablica[y]);
        if (tablica.length > 1 && y != tablica.length - 1 ) {
            wynik.append(" ");
        }
        y++;
    }
    return wynik.toString();
}   
}
```

Tester

```
public class PrimeCheckerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrimeChecker obiekt = new PrimeChecker();
        System.out.println(obiekt.spinWords("Hey fellow warriors").toString());     
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo: `int y = 0;` should be out of loop.

Comment: Which means that you currently, at each iteration, overwrite `y` again with the default `0` value.

Comment: oh my God, i'm so blind, thanks :o

Comment: You also have a lot of `toString()` method calls in there. You don't need the one in prntln, since your spinWords returns a string. You don't have to `toString` a `String`

Comment: Since Java 8 we have String.join so second loop may be replaced by it.

Comment: If the code used for-each-style loops, and did not try to reuse `tablica` but created a new result list, the error would not be able to happen.

Comment: You all guys are very helpful, I'm beginner, that's why this code is so extensive. Thank's a lot

Answer (score 2):

First, I would prefer to split with `\\s+` which matches one or more white-space characters. Second, I would use a lambda with `Arrays.stream` on the tokens I `split`. Then I would `map` each word, reversing every word with 5 or more characters. That can be done with a `StringBuilder` and `reverse()`. And since this method doesn't need any instance state we can make it `static`. Finally, join the words backs together with a `Collector`. Like,

```
public static String spinWords(String sentence) {
    return Arrays.stream(sentence.split("\\s+"))
            .map(s -> s.length() >= 5 ? new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString() : s)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

And to test it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(spinWords("Hey fellow warriors"));
}
```

Which gives (as specified)

```
Hey wollef sroirraw
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm beginner that's why I don't even know map and collect mechanics and this syntax you presented, but amazing how short and clear my code would be.

Answer (score 1):

This code below will work. You have added y=0 inside the loop. That is unnecessary.

```
public class PrimeChecker {

public String spinWords(String sentence) {

String[] tablica = sentence.split(" ");
int y = 0;
for ( String x : tablica ) {

    if (  x.length() >= 5 ) {
        StringBuilder p = new StringBuilder(x).reverse();
        x = p.toString();
    }
    tablica[y] = x;
    y++;            
}

StringBuilder wynik = new StringBuilder();
y=0;
for ( String z : tablica ) {

    tablica[y] = z;
    wynik.append(tablica[y]);
    if (tablica.length > 1 && y != tablica.length - 1 ) {
        wynik.append(" ");
    }
    y++;
}
return wynik.toString();
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define y out of `for loop` and before the second loop give it the value of zero , because you reset the value of y each loop .

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a simpler way:

```
public String spinWords(String sentence) {

    String[] tablica = sentence.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < tablica.length; i++) {

        if(tablica[i].length() >= 5) {
            StringBuilder p = new StringBuilder(tablica[i]).reverse();
            tablica[i] = p.toString();
        }
    }

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s : tablica) {
        builder.append(s + " ");
    }
    String str = builder.toString();

    return str;
}
```